# Spreadsheet styles.xml shows alpha value for fonts as zero

Tags: xml, fonts, openxml, spreadsheet

I got a wierd ooxml spreadhsheet document whose styles.xml has the following content :

```
-<fonts count="3">
-<font>
<sz val="10"/>
 <color rgb="FF000000"/>
 <name val="Arial"/>
</font>
-<font>
<sz val="9"/>
 <color rgb="00333333"/>
 <name val="Arial"/>
 </font>
-<font>
<b/>
<sz val="9"/>
<color rgb="00FFFFFF"/>
<name val="Arial"/>
</font>
</fonts>
```

I am unable to render it on the screen, since the alpha value for the fonts is set to zero in this case. If I re-save the document again, the alpha value in styles.xml changes to 0xFF and the content is visible on the screen. The entire code for reading the values in written in C using XML Parser. The original document is able to open fine in Office suite. Is it that Office suite is discarding alpha values for the fonts or applying a workaround to view the document? Are there some other values in styles.xml that I should be looking for in alpha value for the fonts is set to zero so I can render the content on the screen?Any pointers.

or In other words, what other properties can help if alpha value of font is zero but the content should still be visible? Probably, another value in the xml file that I may be ignoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there was an issue in the xml itself, as if someone has explicitly modified it. Fixed it by checking for the `color theme` value while reading fonts in `styles.xml` and if not set, set the alpha value of the font to 0xFF and voila, everything works

Re-saving the same document once again causes the font's alpha value to be reset to 0xFF, hence, proving my point.